# I want to write a sublist rule but SWI-Prolog doesn't make it past rule declaration line

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and I wanted to create a rule that takes a list in this format [(X,Y,Z)|Tail] and creates a new list only with the Y's. I wrote this but the compiler doesn't make it past the rule declaration line. Am I doing this the wrong way?

```
sublist([], []).
sublist([Phead | (_,Membro,_)], [Lhead | Ltail]) :-
    Ltail is Membro,
    sublist(Phead, Lhead).
```

Comment: This is at least syntactically valid. What does the compiler say exactly?

Comment: And evidently you are using `is/2`, which is used for arithmetic evaluation in the way of an assignment operator from imperative programming. Big NOPE. Also reflect on why `Ltail := Membro` makes absolutely no sense given your problem statement.

Comment: Using the trace functionality, I can see that it returns false when running this line:
sublist([Phead | (_,Membro,_)], [Lhead | Ltail]) :-

I wrote this line one the compiler: sublist([(start, beijing, 0),  (train,hong_kong, 13), (bus,bombay,23)],City_list)

Comment: Did you wanna say that Ltail=Membro also makes no sense? Thank you for your replies btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code needs some change.

How do we relate the "input list" and the "output list" to fulfill the specification?

We are in luck, as the specification allows us to relate the elements in the "input list" (left) and "output list" (right) one-to-one, thus:

```
sublist( [ LeftHead | LeftTail ] , [ RightHead | RightTail ] ) :-
   relate_element(LeftHead, RightHead),
   relate_lists(LeftTail, RightTail).
```

Relating the tails w/o the current heads is the same as relating any list, so:

```
sublist( [ LeftHead | LeftTail ] , [ RightHead | RightTail ] ) :-
   relate_element(LeftHead, RightHead),
   sublist(LeftTail, RightTail).
```

And an empty list on the left relates to an an empty list on the right, so the base case is (correctly):

```
sublist([], []).
```

The base case cannot be confused with the "normal" case because the arguments in the head `sublist( [ LeftHead | LeftTail ] , [ RightHead | RightTail ] ) :-` do not match the empty list, so there is no need to add any additional checks in the bodies of clauses for base and usual case to keep them apart. Nice.

Now, what about the `relate_element(LeftHead, RightHead)`?

Let's program out `relate_element(LeftHead, RightHead) :- ....`.

The specification says that the "left head" is of the form `(X,Y,Z)` (this is BAD form, far better would be `[X,Y,Z]`, but let's let that dog lie).

So we are only interested in calls which match a `LeftHead` thusly:

```
relate_element((X,Y,Z), RightHead) :- ...
```

And the specification says `RightHead` should only be `Y`. Okay!

```
relate_element((X,Y,Z), Y) :- ...
```

What happens in the body when a match for the head arguments is obtained? Well, nothing, just success.

```
relate_element((X,Y,Z), Y) :- true.
```

Simplify to

```
relate_element((X,Y,Z), Y).
```

Öur program:

```
sublist([], []).
sublist( [ LeftHead | LeftTail ] , [ RightHead | RightTail ] ) :-
   relate_element(LeftHead, RightHead),
   sublist(LeftTail, RightTail).

relate_element((X,Y,Z), Y).
```

But you can also state that `LeftHead` must be `(X,Y,Z)` from the very beginning, similarly to `RightHead` being `Y`. Thus

```
sublist([], []).
sublist( [ (X,Y,Z) | LeftTail ] , [ Y | RightTail ] ) :-
   relate_element((X,Y,Z), Y),
   sublist(LeftTail, RightTail).

relate_element((X,Y,Z), Y).
```

`relate_element/2` now does nothing at all, so let's simplify (and mark singleton variables with `_`):

```
sublist([], []).
sublist( [ (_X,Y,_Z) | LeftTail ] , [ Y | RightTail ] ) :-
   sublist(LeftTail, RightTail).
```

Does it work? With [`plunit`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/plunit.html%27)), let's sample whether the rights things are indeed related and the wrong things are not related:

```
:- begin_tests(sublist).

test(one) :- sublist([],[]).
test(two) :- sublist([(a,b,c),(e,f,g),(h,i,j)],[b,f,i]).
test(three,fail) :- sublist([(a,b,c),(1,2),(h,i,j)],_).
test(four,fail)  :- sublist([(a,b,c),(e,f,g),(h,i,j)],[b,x,i]).
test(five,fail)  :- sublist([(a,b,c),(e,f,g),(h,i,j)],[]).

:- end_tests(sublist).

rt(sublist) :- run_tests(sublist).
```

Then

```
?- rt(_X).
% PL-Unit: sublist ..... done
% All 5 tests passed
_X = sublist.
```

You can test whether the predicate works "backwards" too. Indeed it does, emitting am "template" for the input:

```
?- sublist(X,[b,f,i]).
X = [(_10626, b, _10634),  (_10644, f, _10652),  (_10662, i, _10670)].
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This is a weird language to get accostumed to and it was really helpful to see your thought process to reach this final goal. 
It's very interesting that for such an intricate thought process, we get only two or three lines of code. I guess that's the beauty of Prolog :)

Comment: @JoãoVaz Glad to be of help. Do not forget to "accept answer" please.